# How to pass a dynamic array of structs to a member function?

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, member-functions

I am wondering how I can pass a dynamically allocated array of structures from the main function to a member function of a class. I don't necessarily need to change its values in the member function, just print it.

If I do it like I would with an integer array in the following code snippet, I get that `MyStruct` is not defined in the `MyClass.h` and `MyClass.cpp` files. (Which makes sense)
If I include `main.cpp` in `MyClass.h` I get a lot of weird errors. Another idea was prepending `struct` in the member function parameter, but that lead to other errors as well.

I need to declare the struct array outside of the class, not as a member, and I cannot use STL containers.

**main.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

int main()
{
    MyClass my_class;

    struct MyStruct
    {
        int a;
        int b;
    };

    MyStruct* struct_array = new MyStruct[4];
    // Fill struct array with values...
    my_class.printStructArray(struct_array);
}
```

**MyClass.h**:

```
#include <iostream>
class MyClass
{
    // ...
    void printStructArray(MyStruct* struct_array);
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void MyClass::printStructArray(MyStruct* struct_array)
{
    std::cout << struct_array[0].a << struct_array[0].b;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Why can't you use standard containers?

Comment: Because this could be in a loop going on millions of times and someone insists that the STL containers are too slow for our performance requirements. I can't really comment on that since I'm only an intern.

If it's too complicated this way I'll use an STL container.

Comment: I am gong to call BS on whoever told you that.  A vector should be as fast as an array when compiled with optimizations on.  It was built to be a replacement to DIY dynamic arrays.

Comment: I thought so too, I'll definitely use them otherwise when I'm not just the lowly intern ;)

Comment: I think you should pass the size of the array to your function, if you are not using a STL container.

Comment: @RobertJacobs I am doing that, I just left it out here, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just move the `struct` definition into `MyClass.h` or it's own separate header file:

**MyClass.h**

```
#include <iostream>

struct MyStruct {
  int a, b;
};
class MyClass {
  // ...
  void printStructArray(MyStruct* struct_array);
};
```

Comment: That did the trick, I totally forgot that you can define stuff inside a class header file or a separate header file without making it a member of that class. Thanks!